# Remove 2nd level Sub Directories

Tags: powershell-2.0, directory, subdirectory

The script below finds folders in the `E:\WebDelivery\MagicOS` directory. If any of the folders in this directory are older than 14 days it will then delete them and their sub-directories. It excludes files that are named `upd.info.raf.`

I need to change the script to only look in the sub-directory for the modified date and if that date is older than 14 days, it needs to delete those folders and their contents but leave the `S6.15`, `T7.12` type parent directory alone.

Here is the folder structure:
`E:\WebDelivery\MagicOS`  ->> under this are the directories `S6.15, T7.12, S5.6` etc. and under each of those there are directories all with numbers as names 1, 2,3 etc and possibly a file called `upd.info.raf`

```
E\WebDelivery\MagicOS ->> S6.15 
                         ->> 1
                         ->> 2
```

Currently the script is checking the `S6.15` level folders for the modified date and removing the folder and it's sub-directories if they are older than 14 days. I need instead to check the number sub directories 1, 2, 3 etc for modified dates and remove those if they are older then 14 days but leave the parent S6.15 directory. Basically I don't care about the date on the `S6.15` folder only the number sub folders 1, 2, 3 etc...

This is where I'm stumped. Any ideas would be helpful. Here is the existing script.

```
    $Today = Get-Date
    $DaysToKeep = 14
    $TargetFolder = "E:\WebDelivery\MagicOS"
    $LastWrite = $Today.AddDays(-$DaysToKeep)
    $excludeFolders = @("testdir","testdir2")

    $Folders = Get-Childitem –path $Targetfolder |
    Where {$_.psIsContainer} |
    Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} |
    Where {$excludeFolders -notcontains $_.Name}

    If ($Folders) {
        foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
            Write-Host "Processing Folder $($Folder.Name)"
            $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Exclude 
    "upd.info.raf" -Recurse
            If ($items) {
        Write-Host "Removing: $($Folder.Name)"
               # $items | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose
            } Else {
                Write-Host "There are no items to remove in $($Folder.Name)"
            }
       }
    } Else {
    Write-Host "There are no folders to empty."
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure this out on my own. I added a `foreach` loop to process each child-item of the sub directory and remove the old folders.

Here is the modified script:

```
$Today = Get-Date
$DaysToKeep = 14
$TargetFolder = "E:\WebDelivery\testdir"
$LastWrite = $Today.AddDays(-$DaysToKeep)
$excludeFolders = @("testdir","testdir2")

$Folders = Get-Childitem –path $Targetfolder |
Where {$_.psIsContainer} |
Where {$excludeFolders -notcontains $_.Name}

If ($Folders) {
 foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
        Write-Host "Processing Folder $($Folder.Name)"
        $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder.FullName -Exclude 
"upd.info.raf" | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 
        If ($items) {
      foreach ($item in $items){
        Write-Host "Removing: $($item.FullName)"
        $item | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose
        } 

        } Else {
            Write-Host "There are no items to remove in $($Folder.Name)"
        }
  }  
}  Else {
Write-Host "There are no folders to empty."
```